# react query returns stale data on second page load

Tags: react-query

I work in next js app router with react query.

I have a route `record?collection=1&id=1` that fetches the record and displays it for editing. To make sure the edited data is not constantly overwritten I have a useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("pre setting record", "d:", data?.name, "r: ", record.name);
    if (!data) return;
    if (Object.keys(record).length > 0) return;
    setRecord({ ...data });
  }, [data, collection]);
```

when i navigate to the route the first time everything is fine, however, when I go to a different route, edit the record and navigate back to `record?collection=1&id=1` through router.push(), the initial data returned by useQuery will be old. Through the console.log in the useEffect I can tell the initial data returned is wrong. I tried to invalidate the query when navigating away as such:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries();
    };
  }, [queryClient]);
```

however this does nothing. Does anyone know how to fix this? I would be ok with a complete refresh on navigation aswell.
thanks

Comment: if you want to invalidateQueries you have pass queryKey like this `queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['your-key'] })`
But this seems like wrong approach for your case. Can you show your useQuery hook?

Comment: hi, i think queryClient.invalidateQueries() invalidates all queries. I got it working by returning queryClient.removeQuery(queryKey) from a useEffect. I assume reactQuery returns data it knows to be stale, as it might be a better placeholder than nothing? but in my case that kinda messed things up

Comment: No, you have to provide queryKeys to it. https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientinvalidatequeries